# Why does eos produce continuous blocks?

Tags: nodeos, block-producer, blocks, producers

I am wondering about permanently producing blocks. Can someone explain why we need this ?

Answer (score 7):

Blocks always need to be produced due to there always being the potential for an action to be sent to the chain. If blocks are not produced, that action would then have additional latency added to it for the time it would take the chain to start and produce a block for one action.  Also, if the chain is not flowing, there would not be a mechanism for discerning which BP is producing the block.

If you could add more detail to your question, maybe I can provide a better answer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought blocks only created when we send a transaction. This structure suprised me.